# Screenshot a page using Selenium and Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: selenium, screenshot, chromium-embedded

I am using [Selenium with my Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver). So far so good. Now I am trying to take a screenshot.

The Chrome webdriver supports screenshots, but it doesn't work in CEF. Specifically I get this error:

> UnknownError: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
>   from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html

Does the Chrome webdriver use a Chrome extension for screenshots under-the-hood? I know that CEF does not support Chrome Extensions per [this thread](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10242). Does anyone else have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real solution but I worked around the issue by:

1. Create an HTTP server in my native application (only in debug mode)
2. Implement a native way in my application to take a screenshot of the current window
3. The Selenium Java test send a request to the test server
4. Server-side it call the native implementation to take a screenshot

Just a reminder it's a workaround! Waiting the support of Selenium screenshot.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that is a solution. There is definitely no native support, as I found out at http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12967. For me, with some debug modification to my content, I just did the screenshot using Chrome.

Comment: If I might ask, how did you do (2) Implement a native way in your application to take a screenshot of the current window?

Comment: @chowey I was already using SFML in my c++ application, and this library provide a method to capture a window.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with the recent chrome-browser 58.0.3018.3 dev (64-bit) on MBP and ChromeDriver 2.27.440174. Here is the verified solution. Hope it could help people who are searching work around.

Refer to [forum](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1625), experimental option is a work around `options.setExperimentalOption("forceDevToolsScreenshot", true);`.